# How can I get best val_acc and val_loss simultaneously in CNN using keras?

Tags: keras

I've used `ModelCheckpoint(file_path, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')` to get the max val_acc. So, when i run my program I get a many of sample such as:

1. val_acc = 0.92857 & val_loss = 0.2495,
2. val_acc = 0.98750 & val_loss = 0.6820.

So, it takes 2 no., although it's val_loss in large.
How can I choose the no. 1 with lower val_loss?
Alternatively, how can i choose the best fitted model keeping val_acc and val_loss value in mind?

Comment: if you save as hist = model.fit(...), then you can get the following: 
train_loss, val_loss, train_acc, val_acc = hist.history['loss'], hist.history['val_loss'], hist.history['acc'], hist.history['val_acc']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really just factor one of them for your checkpoint. However, you could just create two callbacks and save the network based on both metrics.

```
call_acc = ModelCheckpoint(weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5, monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True, mode='max')
call_loss = ModelCheckpoint(weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5, monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, mode='min')
model.fit(X, Y, epochs, batch_siz, callbacks=[call_loss, call_acc])
```